# SEO optimizing Blogger blogspots

Tags: seo, blog, blogger

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

What are some way to optimize a Blogger blogspot for SEO? I have looked at several other articles, but they were old, so the tactics used won't work with the newer Blogger.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by 'tactics'?

The tactics haven't changed since the dropping of support by most major search engines for the meta keywords tag.

Since then, the tactics have consisted of creating brilliant content.

Comment: What I mean is it requires you to edit HTML (which I don't have a problem with), but the HTML that it says to edit isn't even there. I.E. There used to be a <mainpage> tag that encompassed the whole middle column. There isn't now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick list of way to do this. However, the standard list applies as well.

- The best thing to do from a coding standpoint is to find a good
  theme. One that has semantic HTML and good meta data.
- Be sure to use internal and external links. You can do this by
  tagging posts and linking to quality content.
- Next you can be sure to use a good subdomain that has the keywords
  you want.
- great content helps